# What is an error-guessing test case?

Tags: testing

I would need a simple explanation on what a error-guessing test case it. Is it dangerous to use? I would appreciate an example.

Best regards,
Erica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error guessing is documented here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_guessing

It's a name for something that's very common -- guessing where errors might occur based on your previous experience.

For example you have a routine that calculates whether a value inputted by a user from a terminal is a prime number:

You'd test the cases where errors tend to occur:

1. Empty input
2. Values that are not integers (floating point, letters, etc)
3. Values that are boundary cases 2, 3, 4
   etc.

I would assume that every tester/QA person would be asked questions like this during an interview. It gives you a chance to talk about what procedures you've used in the past during testing.

I think the method goes like this:
1. Do formal testing
2. Use knowledge gained during formal testing about how the system works to make a list of places where defects might be
3. Design tests to verify whether those defects exist.

By its nature this process is very ad-hoc and unstructured.

Comment: Is there any "standardized" way of designing this test kind of test-cases? And also, what can the problems be?

Comment: I added a comment. By it's nature "Guessing" there's no standard. I added a little info about the process. Hope that helps.